# Vue different methods notation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

What is the difference between these two notations? For example:

```
...
methods: {
  makeAuthorList() {
    return ...
  },
}
...
```

**and**

```
...
methods: {
  makeAuthorList: function(){
    return ...
  },
}
...
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, I'd also like to add that this isn't specific to Vue and is available in vanilla JavaScript as of ES2015.

Answer (score 1):

Both are identical, the first one is just a shorter syntax for method definitions starting with ES2015. Take a look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) from the MDN docs.

Answer (score 1):

functionally they don't have a difference, they do the exact same thing, this way:

```
nameOfFunction: function(){}
```

is just a long way to define your methods, so they added a second way to define methods which is a shorter version, just so save time

```
nameOfFunction() {}
```

[best pratices vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide)

Comment: Then you can also work with arrow functions, right?

Comment: @MaikLowrey you should avoid trying arrow functions in your method section. You can [read here about why](https://michaelnthiessen.com/this-is-undefined/).